# Expected value of discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to prove $$
E(X)=\sum (1-F_{X(k)}) 
$$

I managed to do the same with continuous variable using change of integral but cannot do for discrete. Really appreciate anyhelp

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273376/suppose-that-x-is-a-discrete-random-variable-taking-values-in-0-1-2/

Answer (score 0):

For $X\in\Bbb N$ a.s., you want :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~=~& \sum_{s=0}^\infty s P_X(s) \\ =~& 0+\sum_{s=1}^\infty \sum_{t=1}^s P_X(s) \\=~&\sum_{1\leq t\leq s }P_X(s)\\ \vdots~~~&\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\mathbb P(X \in \mathbb N)=1$, then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &=  \sum_{j=1}^\infty j\ \mathbb P(X=j)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^j  \mathbb P(X=j) \tag 1\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=i}^\infty  \mathbb P(X=j)\tag 2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X\geqslant i)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-F_X(i)\right).
\end{align}
The interchange in order of summation between $(1)$ and $(2)$ is justified by Tonelli's theorem.